# Using immutability-helper in React to set variable object key

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, immutability

I have a function I want to write in React.  In my class I have a state object `fields` that looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  step: 1,
  fields: {
    type: '',
    name: '',
    subtype: '',
    team: '',
    agreement: ''
  }
};
```

I have various functions that assign those keys using `immutability helper` that generally look like:

```
assignType(attribute) {
  var temp = update(this.state.fields, {
    type: {$set: attribute}
  });

  this.setState({
    fields: temp
  });
}
```

What I would *like* to do is use a function that's more generic and do something like this:

```
assignAttribute(field, attribute) {
  var temp = update(this.state.fields, {
    field: {$set: attribute}
  });

  this.setState({
    fields: temp
  });
}
```

But, this doesn't work.  What can I do to use a variable key using `immutability-helper`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Figured it out! I needed to use [ES6 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and simply edit `assignAttribute` to:

```
assignAttribute(field, attribute) {
  var temp = update(this.state.fields, {
    [field]: {$set: attribute}
  });

  this.setState({
    fields: temp
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice find. Did not know about this ES6 feature. See the other answer for the more clumsy "old way".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `[]` syntax if you have dynamic field names:

```
var data = {}
data[field] = {$set: attribute}

var temp = update(this.state.fields, data)
```

This gets [a lot more concise if you can use ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404660/14955).